# Laravel 5 upload shows blank page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a website with CMS developed using laravel 5 I have the following folder structure

[image]

I am trying to upload it to the server what I did was I created a folder called beta inside the public_html which contained all of my public folder contents i.e the backend,frontend source,uploads and db folder as shown in image below and I kept the CMS folder outside the public_html I modified few paths i.e. in the index.php I have the paths set-up as

```
require __DIR__.'/../../CMS/bootstrap/autoload.php' ;

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../CMS/bootstrap/app.php';
```

All I get is a blank page am I missing some changes in  paths or what might be the problem. This problem is killing me.

This is the error log although I've helper.php file inside the required folder

```
[15-Jun-2015 06:37:39 America/Detroit] PHP Warning:  require(/home/dinwaub/CMS/app/http/helpers/backend/helpers.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/domain/CMS/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59
```

This is part of my composer.json file which contains the path to the helper.php file

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },

        "files": [

            "app/http/helpers/backend/helpers.php",
            "app/http/helpers/frontend/viewHelper.php" 
        ]

    },
```

This is how it looks in the server

This is the CMS folder that is outside the public_html folder
[image]

This is the beta folder which is inside public_html
[image]

These are the folders inside beta folder
[image]

Comment: You have an .env.example file in your root folder. Remove the .example part and you'll get an error. Or you don't have one at all, in which case you should create one.

Comment: i have already removed the .env.example file I only have the .env file still it shows no error and only give blank page@Andrew

Comment: Is the enviroment set to production by any chance? Is the debug mode set to true?

Comment: no it is still not working still gives the blank page@Andrew

Answer (score 0):

I think the configuration should be

```
require __DIR__.'/../../../CMS/bootstrap/autoload.php' ;

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../CMS/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Since `__DIR__` is current file directory and `../` is going up one level

Comment: the pic is only showing my folder structure in my pc actually when I uploaded the project the CMS folder is outside the public_html folder and the index.php is inside a folder called beta inside public_html

Comment: Is there any index.php file inside public_html? And is the system set to look inside the beta folder for the index.php file? Can you create an index.html file with "Hello" just to test from which folder your system is set to "start"?

Comment: can you take screenshot of current folder structure in server?

Comment: I have provided some screenshots have a look @Nikko

Comment: I used var_dump('test') inside my index.php and it works fine but If I take the same var_dump('test') after the require __DIR__.'/../../../CMS/bootstrap/autoload.php' ; nothing shows up @Boris

Comment: I would say that its a path problem. Please review your include/require paths.

Comment: your `index.php` configuration is okay but some of your file is missing. I even doesn't have `helpers` folder inside my `app/http`, sorry I couldn't help you more.

Comment: there is a helpers folder inside the app/http@Nikko